# ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed? PIL Python3

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
root@syscomp1:~# cd Pillow-master
root@syscomp1:~/Pillow-master# python3 selftest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selftest.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "./PIL/Image.py", line 155, in <module>
    if hasattr(core, 'DEFAULT_STRATEGY'):
  File "./PIL/Image.py", line 39, in __getattr__
    raise ImportError("The _imaging C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed
root@syscomp1:~/Pillow-master#
```

### this is the step before i install PIL

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential 
sudo pip install --upgrade pip 
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv 
sudo aptitude install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
download the Pillow-master.zip
wget https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/archive/master.zip
go to downloaded directory and,
sudo unzip master.zip
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-dev //must install this
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get install liblcms1-dev
python3 setup.py build_ext -i
```

but error with `The _imaging C module is not installed` why?

Comment: Can you see whether the compiled modules are actually around? Simply look for so files in the main directory: `ls *.so`. If you can't find them, you must have had an error during the build of the extension, so look for that next (just rerun the build).

Comment: @Evert do you mean `python3 setup.py build` again?does not work, i have tried so many times of this command

Comment: But is there an error message? And check the other thing: are there any .so files?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Python 2 print statement in setup.py:

```
  Downloading from URL http://effbot.org/media/downloads/PIL-1.1.7.tar.gz (from http://effbot.org/downloads/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pil

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

      File "<pyenv>/build/pil/setup.py", line 182

        print "--- using Tcl/Tk libraries at", TCL_ROOT
```